# How to combine Manipulate and OutputResponse to manipulate a transfer function

Tags: manipulate, control-systems

The [webpage on Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) provides an example on section Examples > Applications of how to manipulate two parameters (the initial conditions) of an Initial Value Problem (ODE with initial conditions), which is the following (I've removed `Epilog` and `ImagePadding` because they're not interesting):

[image: Example]

Instead of plotting the solution to an ODE, I'd like to plot the step response of a system given its transfer function. The transfer function is:

$\dfrac{\dfrac{5}{s^2+2s} K_1}{1+\dfrac{5}{s^2+2s} (K_2 s+K_1)} \tag*{}$

where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the parameters I want to manipulate. So, tried to change `Evaluate` with the following code:

```
OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[(5/(s^2 + 2 s)*K1)/(1 + 5/(s^2 + 2 s)*(K2*s + K1)), s], UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

but Mathematica doesn't show the plot:

[image: My attempt]

What's wrong? What would be the appropriate code?

Comment: This works:Manipulate[
 fun = OutputResponse[
    TransferFunctionModel[(5/(s^2 + 2 s)*K1)/(1 + 
        5/(s^2 + 2 s)*(K2*s + K1)), s]
    , UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}][[1]];
 Print[fun];
 Plot[fun, {t, 0, 4}]
 , {{K1, 1}, 0, 3}, {{K2, 1}, 0, 3}]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@
   OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[(5/(s^2 + 2 s)*K1)/(1 + 
        5/(s^2 + 2 s)*(K2*s + K1)), s], UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}],
   {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}], {{K1, 1}, 0, 3}, {{K2, 2}, 0, 3}]
```

[image]